# Is it possible to change the display server of a running x window client application?

Tags: x11, environment

I wonder whether it is possible to change the display server IP of a running x window client application.

More specifically:
- i would login to a server remotely (IP 1.1.1.1)
- i would set the DISPLAY environment variable to the IP of my x window server on my laptop (IP 10.0.0.1)
- i would start the x windows client application on the remote server (IP 1.1.1.1) which would be displayed on IP 10.0.0.1

The question: is it possible that while the client application is running on IP 1.1.1.1 and displayed on IP 10.0.0.1 to change the display server to IP 10.0.0.2?

Comment: This question should be migrated to `superuser.com`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

X11 by default does not support this, but there are various applications that allow the relocation of applications to other screens, including but not limited to:

- Xpra
- xmove
- lbxproxy
- guievict

And of course the usual stack of non-X11 remote deskops, including VNC and NX.

P.S. This question should be on "superuser"!